# counter_cache has_many_through sql optimisation, reduce number of sql queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord, model

How I can optimise my SQL queries, to ignore situations like this:

> Meeting.find(5).users.size => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...
>
> User.find(123).meetings.size => SELECT COUNT(*) FROm ... WHERE ...

I have no idea how to use counter_cache here.

Here is my model relation:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meeting_users
  has_many :users, :through => meeting_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meeting_users
  has_many :meetings, :through => meeting_users
end

class Meeting_user < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What are the most optimal solutions ?

And how implement counter_cache here ?

Comment: Would anything here prevent you from doing something like MeetingUser.where(:meeting_id => 5, :user_id => 123).size for both situations?  At least in that case you'd be able to take advantage of SQL query caching.  The default implementation of counter_cache won't really help you in this sort of situation.

Comment: I think You are wrong. counter_cache will help here. For example when You render a list of users in the view, and You will display in each line how many meetings each user has ? With counter_cache this will be one SQL query, without it will be 1+n*Users.size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use `counter_cache` with `through` associations, that's why you should manually increment it.

For example (untested):

```
class MeetingUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  after_create { |record| 
    Meeting.increment_counter(:users_count, record.meeting.id)
  }

  after_destroy { |record| 
    Meeting.decrement_counter(:users_count, record.meeting.id)
  }

end
```

Answer (score 22):

Starting from Rails3.0.5 and in newer versions, you are now able to set counter cache to the "linker" model, in your case it will be:

```
class MeetingUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting, :counter_cache => :users_count
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => :meetings_count
end
```

It's important to explicitly specify count column names, otherwise the columns used will default to `meeting_users_count`.

Comment: This worked for me. Less code than the after_create... solution

Comment: Works better for me too! After create events are skipped on mass assignment. This should be the accepted answer.