# counter_cache with has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just created a counter_cache field and the controller looks like this.

```
 @users = User.where(:sex => 2).order('received_likes_count')
```

The association in User.rb is

```
 has_many :received_likes, :through => :attachments, :source => :likes, :dependent => :destroy
```

Problem is that counter_cache is declared in the belong_to of Like.rb and I don't know how to tell it that is for the has_many :through association.

```
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => :received_likes
```

Answer (score 27):

You have previous

```
    class Product
      has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    end

    class Category
      has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    end
```

and migration

```
    class CreateCategoriesProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :categories_products, id: false do |t|
          t.references :category
          t.references :product
        end

        add_index :categories_products, [:category_id, :product_id]
      end
    end
```

now change all to

```
    class Product
      has_many :categories_products, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :categories, through: :categories_products
    end

    class Category
      has_many :categories_products, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :products, through: :categories_products
    end
```

and new one

```
    class CategoriesProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
      # this model uses table "categories_products" as it is
      # column products_count is in the table "categories"
      belongs_to :category, counter_cache: :products_count
      belongs_to :product
    end
```

Comment: In other words, when you have a `has_many :through` relationship, you define any and all `counter_cache`'s on the `:through` model.

You could complement the first `counter_cache: :products_count` by extending the second relationship: `belongs_to :product, counter_cache: :categories_count`

Comment: Thanks, works on Rails 4.2. To correctly process product deletion, it is needed to add "dependent: :destroy" option to both "has_many :categories_products" statements.

Comment: Works as expected with Rails 4.2.

Comment: @TatianaTyu The same on Rails 4.1

Comment: @Martin I know it's been 5 years and all, but you should mark this as the answer :)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Pay attention to the pluralization of the model representing the join table. That can trip you up. `CategoriesProduct` -- plural then singular.

Answer (score 13):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700247/counter-cache-has-many-through-sql-optimisation-reduce-number-of-sql-queries) (from last month) and [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/138094) (from 2008), it doesn't seem to be possible.  However, the latter post does have code for a workaround (copy/paste'd from that link for your convenience, credit goes to DEfusion in the second link)

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :B

    after_create :increment_A_counter_cache
    after_destroy :decrement_A_counter_cache

    private

    def increment_A_counter_cache
        A.increment_counter( 'c_count', self.B.A.id )
    end

    def decrement_A_counter_cache
        A.decrement_counter( 'c_count', self.B.A.id )
    end
end
```

(This is for a scheme where C belongs_to B, B belongs_to A, A has_many C :through => B

Comment: The solution provided by Aivils looks like a more correct/conventional Rails solution than adding hooks.

Answer (score 3):

This basically does the same thing:

```
after_save :cache_post_count_on_tags

def cache_post_count_on_tags
  tags.each {|t| tag.update_attribute(:posts_count, t.posts.size)}
end
```

And you need a `posts_count` column on tags, or whatever associations you have.

Comment: Actually I think your code won't decrement the counter because after_save I think isn't called after destroy()