# Counter cache on a habtm relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to use counter cache on a habtm relation in rails 3 ?

I really need it to speed up my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in method for `HABTM` but it is simple to make your own counter cache (actually I was doing it many times before I've invented `counter_cache`.

Or use `has_many :throught` instead of `HABTM` association. I never use `HABTM` because it looks awkward for me.

Related topic:

> [counter_cache with has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through)

Comment: The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through) did it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I created a version for HABTM which you [can see here](https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/5255300).

If you have any questions/comments/suggestions, feel free to leave them - or even fork it and let me see :)

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4, `counter_cache` for `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation works great.

Comment: Any links to support this?  I can't get it to work or find any info.