# Querying an atribute of a has many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User table which

```
has_many :meetings, through: registrations
```

I would like to do an ActiveRecord query for something like this

```
User.where("meetings > 0")
```

But obviously there is no "meetings" column in my db. Which model should I add a class method on and what would that method look like? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using a "counter cache" on your association:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: the api docs make it seem like this only works in a belongs_to relationship

Comment: If Foo has_many Bars, then the foos table gets a bars_count field to store the cache of the count, that it's specified on the belongs_to is just the syntax

Comment: PS Googling for "rails counter cache has_many through" gleans this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through