# How do I use counter_cache in this many-to-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I have a `many-to-many` association between a `Post` and a `Tag` model:

**post.rb:**

```
 has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy  
 has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

**tag.rb:**

```
has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
```

**tagging:**

```
attr_accessible :tag_id, :post_id

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag
```

I want to have a page where I list all the tags and how many posts each tag has.

So I added a `posts_count` column to tags:

```
  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 :null => false
    t.integer  "posts_count", :default => 0, :null => false
  end
```

I've used counter cache before:

**reply.rb:**

```
 belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with this `many-to-many` association. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counter cache for a model with a many-to-many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595338/counter-cache-for-a-model-with-a-many-to-many-association)

Comment: @Peter Ha sorry, I can't believe I asked exactly the same question long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use common :counter_cache option for tags. Despite the fact that it counts Taggings objects, which belongs_to (just one) post, this is what you looking for.

```
# tagging:

attr_accessible :tag_id, :post_id

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :tag, :counter_cache => :posts_count

validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => :post_id
```

Validator will prevent the creation of several identical tags for the same posts, thus you can avoid duplicate records.

Comment: Hey it worked, but what did you mean by `append your model with validator of uniqueness?` Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Valey Kvon Not sure if it is the same but I was doing that in tag.rb: `validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true`

Comment: it's the same, but add :scope option.