# Why is this callback with if statement failing when I check for `nilness`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Post` model has the following columns:

```
t.datetime "published_at"
t.string   "status"
```

`published_at` Should only be defined once (the first time the `post.status` equals `"Published"`):

**post.rb:**

```
 before_save :publish_post

 protected

    def publish_post
      if self.status == "Published" && self.published_at.nil?
       self.published_at = Time.now
      end
    end
```

Now, I added a `posts_count` column to the `Tag` model:

```
t.integer  "posts_count", :default => 0, :null => false
```

The counter should only increment and decrement if the `post.status` equals `"Published"` (Shouldn't increment is `post.status` equals `"Draft"`):

**taggings.rb:**

```
  after_save    :increment_tag_counter_cache
  after_destroy :decrement_tag_counter_cache

  private

   def increment_tag_counter_cache
     if self.post.status == "Published" && self.post.published_at.nil?
       Tag.increment_counter(:posts_count, self.tag.id)
     end
   end

   def decrement_tag_counter_cache
      if self.post.status == "Published" && self.post.published_at.nil?
        Tag.decrement_counter(:posts_count, self.tag.id)
      end
    end
```

For some reason, the right now the counter is not being incremented or decremented. I tried removing code and discovered that the problem is this part: `self.post.published_at.nil?`.

I'm not very sure what's going on. I'm pretty sure `published_at` is `nil` at that moment. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that

```
post.status == "Published" && post.published_at is really nil?
```

?

post.published_at can be just **blank**. like ""

```
post.published_at.blank?
```

Examples of .blank? and .nil?:

```
"".nil?
#=> false

nil.nil?
#=> true

nil.blank?
#=> true

"".blank?
#=> true

"  ".blank?
#=> true

"     ".blank?
#=> true   

[].blank?
#=> true

{}.blank?
#=> true
```

Comment: Well, actually I'm not very sure how to tell. But the if statement works if there is only `if post.status == "Published"`. So maybe `post.published_at` is not nil at that moment (not sure how to check).

Comment: type in console: 'post.published_at' and look what does it return. If it is nil you'll see 'nil'. And only if it's really nil post.published_at.nil? returns 'true' otherwise false, even if it just blank.

Comment: here is a draft post from the console: `published_at: nil, status: "Draft"`

Comment: `published_at: nil` says it is really nil. So the first condition `post.status == "Published"` returns false.