# How to "exploit" relationship data already stored in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2. I have following model classes

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions, :foreign_key => 'country_id'
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country, :foreign_key => 'country_id'
  has_many :cities, :foreign_key => 'region_id'
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, :foreign_key => 'region_id'
end
```

and *I would like to make a `City` `belongs_to :country`*.

I know that the simplest way to make that is to add a `country_id` database table column to the `City` database table and to state related ActiveRecord Associations, this way:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :cities, :foreign_key => 'country_id'
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  belongs_to :country, :foreign_key => 'country_id'
end
```

However, in order to store *less database data*, I think I may "use" the data already stored in the `Region` table *since a city belongs to a region which in turn belongs to a country (this implies that a city belongs to a country)* but, in this case, I have no idea on how to properly state ActiveRecord Associations for `City` and `Country` so to "exploit" mentioned relationship informations implicitly present "through" the `Region` model class.

How should I proceed?

---

*Note*: I am "forcing" to state the `belongs_to :country` ActiveRecord Association in the `City` model class because I would like to use the RoR [`:counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache) feature (available *only* for `belongs_to` associations) in order to count cities present in a country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :through option. As I've seen in your comment in the answer below (which by the way, was correct), you'll just have to add this:

```
has_one :country, :through => :region
```

to your City class. If you want to apply counter_cache on country for the cities, then you'll have to establish the relationship in the country class as well, like this:

```
has_many :cities, :through => :regions
```

and then you can have your count column

Comment: By using your code, "where" / "for which association" I should state the `:counter_cache` option?

Comment: You stated you wanted to count the cities of a country, then I would set the counter_cache option for the has_many cities relationship

Comment: and I would define the counter cache myself. Only belongs_to associations support it (which is a rails flaw), and for that reason I would set the an update callback for the country to update its cities cache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

According to the rails documentation, you can specify a `:through` option on a `has_one` relation:

> **:through**
>
> Specifies a Join Model through which to perform the query. Options for :class_name, :primary_key, and :foreign_key are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection. You can only use a :through query through a has_one or belongs_to association on the join model.

So, what you want is to add `has_one :country, :through => :region` to `City`.

Comment: I would like to state the `belongs_to :country` in `City` because I would like to use the RoR [`:counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache) feature in order to count cities present in a country.

Comment: I see. Unless someone else suggests a way to do this natively in rails, you may have to write this functionality yourself.