# rails 3.1, how to calculate answers number using foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following tables:

```
class FinalExam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :pages, :as => :course_unit, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_unit, :polymorphic => true
  has_one :quiz
  has_one :slide
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
end

class Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
end
```

So, we have Answer.Quiz.Page.FinalExam

Given the FianlExam id, what is the fastest way to find all Answers count ? how to get it ?

I can re-design the DB to have `belongs_to :final_exam` in `Answers`

```
class Answers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :final_exam
end
```

this way, I can say `Answers.where(:final_exam_id=> params[:id]).count`

Do I have to change the DB design ? or its a matter of a query ?

I need an expert advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm guessing that `Quiz` should read:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :answers
end
```

If so you can add these lines to your `FinalExam` model:

```
has_many :quizzes, :through => :pages
has_many :answers, :through => :quizzes
```

Allowing you to then call

```
FinalExam.first.answer.count
```

(Note: if you're on a version of Rails < 3.1, you'll need [this plugin](https://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through))

The drawback to this approach is that it becomes slow with a lot of data. In this case, you'd want to set up a counter cache in the FinalExam that updates every time an answer is added. It'd a little more complicated because of the many-layered relationships you have; see this post for more info:

[counter_cache has_many_through sql optimisation, reduce number of sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700247/counter-cache-has-many-through-sql-optimisation-reduce-number-of-sql-queries)

Comment: what about adding "belongs_to :final_exam" to Answer ? and then using: Answers.where(:final_exam_id=> params[:id]).count, do you recommend it to stay away from complexities ?

Comment: You'd also have to add FinalExam has_many :answers. I'd recommend against this, because then you have ambiguous relationships: A final exam's answers who'd be separate from a final exam's quizzes answers. 

You'd have to keep the two sets of answers in sync and it would be a bit of a nightmare. has_many :through is the preferred way to do what you're trying to do.